# what will be the suitable language for code parsing and call graph drawing

Tags: parsing, call-graph

I have an idea to parse some C++/C code and draw a picture (pretty much like a call graph) out of it. But I may draw more than static pictures (some named boxes within) but also hoping that the boxes are relational (connected) so that end-user can adjust the boxes around but the line connecting the boxes are still there.

In other words, the ultimate goal is that the user can interact with the diagram by adjust elements within it.

More advanced feature of the language/framework support for animation is also desired.

And I'm posting here looking for the best language for this idea (C++(in Microsoft MVC framework?) or python etc). Platform (windows vs. Unix) is also something to be determined. May be Java is also a good option in that matter..

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than choosing a langauge to code your tool in, you would be better off finding some tool that can actually parse "C/C++" now and build your solution around that.  Otherwise you will spend the rest of your life trying to build a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing/analyzing C and doing the same for C++ are completely different tasks.

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has parsers and various kinds of [flow analyzers](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html) for [C](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) and [C++](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html).

For C, the analyzers do control and data flow flow analysis, global points-to analysis, and call graph construction using the points-to-analysis.   For C++ (actually C++11), we are working to complete control flow analysis; its a tough language to analyzer.  DMS has built-in machinery for data flow, etc., but it will take us awhile to ties the C++ front end to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If a call graph is all you want, you don't have to parse C++. You can compile it into LLVM IR instead (with llvm-gcc, Dragonegg or Clang) and display your call graph out of the intermediate code. As for the large graphs visualisation, I'm in a desperate search for such a tool myself, beging stuck with Graphviz for now.